# number of compositions of [n] that each contain a largest part

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to generalize for any [n] the number of compositions that each contain a largest part. [1] has only one composition with a unique largest part, [2] has 1, [3] has 3 compositions with a unique largest part, [4] has 6 compositions with a unique largest part, [5] has 12, [6] has 23, and so on... I want to determine if there is a generalization of how many compositions have a unique largest part relative to the total number of compositions 2^(n-1).

Comment: I get 46 for $n=7$. If that's right, it's not in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: @Gerry: It is right, but $20$ for $[6]$ is wrong: it should be $23$. It’s [A$097979$](http://oeis.org/A097979) offset by one position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the sequence [OEIS A$097979$](http://oeis.org/A097979) offset one place; the correct value for $[6]$ is $23$. A very ugly generating function is given, but no recurrence and no closed form.

The $23$ compositions for $6$ are:

$$\begin{array}{l|l}
6&1\text{ permutation}\\
5+1&2\text{ permutations}\\
4+2&2\text{ permutations}\\
4+1+1&3\text{ permutations}\\
3+2+1&6\text{ permutations}\\
3+1+1+1&4\text{ permutations}\\
2+1+1+1+1&5\text{ permutations}\\ \hline
\text{Total}:&23\text{ permutations}
\end{array}$$

Comment: thanks I couldn't tell if a closed form was capable of being formulated, but now i see only by brute force can you tell for any given [n].

Comment: @AlPal: You're welcome.

Comment: would 3+2+1 be 3 permutations? if not can someone explain how it is 6?

Comment: if it was 20 then the pattern looks like a rule of n^2-3n+2

Comment: @EpicGuy: It’s $23$, not $20$, and your formula also fails for $n=7$. There are $6$ permutations of the composition $3+2+1$; the other five are $3+1+2$, $2+1+3$, $2+3+1$, $1+2+3$, and $1+3+2$.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: Ok thanks now I get what a permutation is thx

Comment: I thought it was the number of numbers that's how I got 3

Comment: Why isn't 1+1+1+1+1+1 a permutation?

Comment: @EpicGuy: It's a composition of $5$, b and it doesn't have a unique largest part, so it isn't of interest here.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Ok thanks again got it now

Comment: @EpicGuy: You’re welcome.